# RSpec request example failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, request, integration-testing

I'm trying to do a really simple request spec for testing my API methods in my application. Right now I'm getting 302 message when I should be getting 200 with this test.

The spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe UsersController do
  describe "#create" do
    it "creates a new user " do
      post '/users', user: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:user)
      expect(response.status).to eq 200
    end
  end
end
```

The factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:name)  { |n| "Person #{n}" }
    sequence(:username) { |n| "Person#{n}" } 
    sequence(:email) { |n| "person_#{n}@example.com"}
    password "foobar"
    password_confirmation "foobar"
  end
end
```

The controller method:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

What am I missing?

Comment: From your code obivously you mentioned redirect when giving non asynchronous request.

Comment: I actually want to just test the json response, not the html one. What am I missing in my test for that purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the issue I need to add the `ACCEPT` header to my request, like so:

```
post "/users", { user: @user } , { accept: 'application/json' }
```

Doing this fixed the issue which was the server not interpreting the request as expecting json in return.

Answer (score 1):

So you need to make the asynchronous post request, it should be something like below,

```
it "creates a new user " do
  xhr :post, '/users', user: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:user)
  expect(response.status).to eq 200
end
```

Try this, it might work

Comment: This didn't fix the response issue, the issue was that I wasn't setting the Accept header to json so it just returned the html response. Thanks anyways, I'll post an answer with my solution.